# How to unit test a Flink ProcessFunction?

Tags: java, junit, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple ProcessFunction that takes in String as input and gives a String as output. How do I unit test this using Junit? As the processElement method is a void method and returns no value.

```
public class SampleProcessFunction extends ProcessFunction<String, String>{
    @Override
    public void processElement(String content, Context context, Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
        String output = content + "output";
        collector.collect(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: more specific scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to unit test this method, define the expected behavior. In this case, the expected behavior is a single invocation of `Collector::collect` method with `content + "output"` as an argument.
Thereby, this could be tested using mocked collector.

Here is an example using [Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mockito) framework:

```
...

private final Collector<String> collectorMock = Mockito.mock(Collector.class);
private final Context contextMock = Mockito.mock(Context.class);

private final SampleProcessFunction sampleProcessFunction = new SampleProcessFunction();

@Test
public void testProcessElement_shouldInvokeCollector_whenAnyValuePassed() throws Exception {
    // given
    final String content = "hello ";

    // when
    sampleProcessFunction.processElement(content, contextMock, collectorMock);

    // then
    Mockito.verify(collectorMock).collect(content + "output"); // verifies that collector method was invoked with "hello output" exactly once
}

...
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want on object, you can use :

```
    Mockito.atLeastOnce();
    Mockito.doReturn(myCustomObject);
```